# Birt start a section on a new page

Tags: report, birt

I have section A and section B. I want to display section B on a new page completely. When i am using page break it is giving me a blank page between A and B. But i need it to start just after. How can we do that please?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe your blank page isn't really blank? Try setting different background colors for your layout items to see where the blank page comes from.

Comment: Hello i have set different colors on the items as suggested and tested it. But it is not overflowing on the blank pages. The blank pages are still white. I cannot seem to get rid of these. I think they are a side effect of page breaks.